# How to get a shorter Path prompt in powerline10k / zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, powerline

everyone!

In my iterm2 (with zsh, oh-my.zsh and powerline2) terminal if I go to certain directories I have a prompt like this:

```
$ pokemon/electric/pichu/pikachu/raichu
```

I'd like to have a shorter, but still complete, path representation like this:

```
$ P/E/P/P/raichu
```

I have seen this kind of configuration but I haven't been able to set it.

====== EDIT ======
Graphical example:
[image]

Can you help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have  a look at this: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/7089 and this plugin: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/shrink-path

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We need to edit the `.p10k.zsh` file
   (in my case, I am using powerlevel10k on zsh/oh-my-zsh/iTerm)

   ```
   nano .p10k.zsh
   ```

   (or use any other editor of your choice).
2. We search for the line `typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY`
   and add the value as follows:

   ```
   typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY=truncate_from_right
   ```
3. We search for the line `typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DELIMITER`
   and set it empty:

   ```
   typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DELIMITER=
   ```
4. Finally we search for the line `typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DIR_LENGTH`
   and add the value 1:

   ```
   typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DIR_LENGTH=1
   ```

You should be able to see something like this: 
[image: screenshot of prompt with directory shown as "~/D/I/L/[/3/1/Workbook"]

---

In case you are using a standard zsh theme (without powerlevel10k theme) you can try this:

Add to `~/.zshrc`:

```
setopt prompt_subst
PROMPT='\$ /$(printf "%c/" ${(s./.)PWD:h})${PWD:t} '
```

- `(s./.)` – splits a path at `/`.
- `printf "%c/"` – prints the first character of each directory piece.
- `${PWD:h}` – the 'head' of the current directory, i.e. everything but the last element.
- `${PWD:t}` – the 'tail' / last element in the directory path.

extracted from [Gairfowl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587843/fish-function-prompt-pwd-but-in-zsh/73589008#73589008) to [fish function prompt_pwd but in zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73587843/3960947)

Comment: Note that `printf %c` prints the first byte not first character  (at least not for multibyte characters). You'd need `printf %.1s` for the first character. You'd also need `$PWD:h:u` to convert to uppercase.

Comment: I’m not sure what you were trying to accomplish with that weird formatting.  Please review my edit, and, if I’ve changed your meaning, [fix it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/715983/edit).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
$ set -o extendedglob -o promptsubst
$ PS1='${${${PWD/#%(#b)$HOME(|\/*)/$match[1]}//(#b)([^\/])([^\/]#)\//$match[1]:u/}//\%/%%}$ '
$ cd install/cvs/oh-my-zsh
/I/C/oh-my-zsh$ cd /usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc
/U/S/Z/F/Misc$
```

Or compute that in a `chpwd()` hook to only compute it when the current working directory changes (and also avoid having to enable the dangerous `promptsubst` along with having to escape the `%`s) and store it in `$psvar` referenced with `%v` in your prompts:

```
shorten_PWD() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob
  psvar[1]=${PWD/#%(#b)$HOME(|\/*)/$match[1]}
  psvar[1]=${psvar[1]//(#b)([^\/])([^\/]#)\//$match[1]:u/}
}
chpwd_functions+=(shorten_PWD)
shorten_PWD
PS1='%1v$ '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create links

```
ln -s pokemon P
```

Then you can either do `cd pokemon` or `cd P` and you would get into the same directory.

Comment: Thanks!
The point is not to modify the folders names links or creating aliases just the prompt of the terminal.
What I've seen is that while you navigate through your file systems (regular names) you see the representation on the prompt in a shorter form!

Answer (score 0):

I've make this test :

```
pwd | awk -F/ 'BEGIN{ ORS="/" } END{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){print $i}}'
result : /opt/tools/intel/oneapi
```

and then this one :

```
pwd | awk -F/ 'BEGIN{ ORS="/" } END{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){print substr($i,1,1)}}'
result : /o/t/i/o
```

So, we can try to modify your bashrc like this :

```
function generate_pwd { 
pwd | awk -F/ 'BEGIN{ ORS="/" } END{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){print substr($i,1,1)}}' 
}
export PS1="\$(generate_pwd) => "
```

It works, normally.